# Problem accessing multidimensional array length and fields

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is code to test a multidimensional array

```java
public class Multiarraytest {

    public int size_main = 5;
    public int size_aux = 20;
    
    Multiarraytest() {
        float[][] float_mul = new float[size_main][size_aux];
    }

    void init_int(Multiarraytest mul) {
        int i, j = 0;
        
        while(i < mul.length) {
            while(j < mul[i].length) {
                mul[i][j] = (i + (j/10));
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    }
}
```

But
here are the results of javac Multiarraytest.java.

error: cannot find symbol While(i < mul.length)
^
symbol: variable length
location: variable mul of type Multiarraytest

error: array required, but Multiarraytest found while(j < mul[i].length
^
error: array required, but Multiarraytest found mul[i][j] = (i + (j/10));

I have not found what's going wrong.

- mul is a 2 dimensional array
- mul.length should give the length of the first array
- mul[1] should lead to the array nested in the first case of mul
- mul[1].length should give the length of the array nested in the first case of mul
- mul[1][2] should give access to read/write of the second case of the array nested in the first case of mul.

Where have I made a mistake?

This is a cut down version of what I was doing but same errors are reported. I read tutorial and close copy-cut it. Except it's a float multidimensional array instead of int multidimensional array and I try to fill it in a loop instead at the initializing time.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual output like compiler errors. Post them as code formatted text. In any case, `mul` is defined as `Multiarraytest`. The only array you define to the **local variable** `float_mul` in the constructor, which it is not usable anywhere else. Maybe you meant to declare `float_mul` as a **field**. Then you should also remove the `Multiarraytest mul` parameter from the method `init_int`. Also, as an aside, I highly recommend you familiarize yourself with common Java naming conventions. Java normally uses camel case for methods, variables and fields.

Comment: float[][]
    Multiarraytest() {
        float[][] float_mul = new float[size_main][size_aux];
    }